# How to display data.lenght = 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My app allows the user to get pictures based on a date range. 1 picture per day (ex: start date 2021-01-01, end date 2021-01-04 = 4 pictures).

So, I would like to display the number of pictures shown based on the chosen date range.
The issue is that if I use data.lenght I will get the correct amount of pictures once the user chooses a date range, however, before the user chooses anything data.lenght = 1 and not 0 zero!

I also tried using item.lenght which returns a undefined value and calculating '(end date) - (start date) = result' but I get a Nan value.

The goal is to display Results = (0) before the user searches a data range and display Results = (number of pics on a given date range) once the user makes a search.

Here is the code:

```
 const searchDateRange = async () => {
    const api = await fetch(
      `my api`
    );
    const data = await api.json();
    setData(data);

  };
```

then I display this:

```
 <Text style={styles.resultsText}>Results ({data.length})</Text>
      </View>

    
      <View style={styles.imageGrid}>
        
        <FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item, index)=>{return item.date}}
        numColumns={numberOfCols}
        renderItem={({item, index})=>(
          <View style={styles.viewpic}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ImageDetails', item)}>
            <Image 
            style={{
    height: 115,
    width: square - 12,
    margin:6,
    }} 
    source={{uri:item.url}}/>
    
    </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
```

thanks everyone for your help!
Cheers!

Comment: Try this:  ({ (data.length).toString() })

Comment: @54ka It shows results = 1 and not 0. :(

Comment: You must have some statе. And by default this state is an empty array. When a person makes his choice, you must filter the new array data and attach the filtered data to this state.

Comment: the state I got is for the data -   const [data, setData] = useState([[]]);
I don't understand  what you mean by "filter the new array data and attach the filtered data to this state"

Comment: Please show an example of what your state looks like and when it has data!

Comment: I get something like this: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]

0
: 
copyright
: 
"name"
date
: 
"2022-01-01"
explanation
: 
"explanation..."
hdurl
: 
"A link"
media_type
: 
"image"
service_version
: 
"v1"
title
: 
"Ttitle"
url
: 
"Link"

Comment: `[[]]` is an array with one element (which is itself an empty array). If you want an empty array you should write simply `[]`.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie thanks a lot. Such a simple solution for an annoying issue lol!

Comment: @54ka thanks for your help! Guillaume's solution fixed my issue.